# asp.net Core 1.1 chunked responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Hopefully, someone can enlighten me on the following.

I have a client that will do a request to a controller endpoint (there is no view, c# to c# or even C++ later). That controller will have to send responses as it fetches them asynchronously as json (sends json1 to client, then json2, then json3 until it closes the connection or send a null terminated text or similar). The purpose is to stream the results back to the client so it can start processing while the server still works.

My controller endpoint looks like this:

```
        [HttpGet("testStream")]
        public async Task testStream()
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Response;
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.TransferEncoding] = "chunked";


            for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                await response.WriteAsync($"6\r\ntest {i}\r\n");

                await response.Body.FlushAsync();
                await Task.Delay(1 * 1000);
            }
            await response.WriteAsync("0\r\n\r\n");
            await response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
```

My test looks like this:

```
        static async void DownloadPageAsync()
        {
            // ... Target page.
            string page = "http://localhost:8080/api/Stream/testStream";
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            while (!Debugger.IsAttached) Thread.Sleep(500);
            // ... Use HttpClient.
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                while (result != "null");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("END");
        }
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            TestSurvey.DownloadPageAsync();
        }
```

I am getting exception when I call `content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Error while copying content to a stream.
[xUnit.net 00:01:14.5836121]       ---- System.IO.IOException : The read operation failed, see inner exception.
[xUnit.net 00:01:14.5836496]       -------- System.Net.Http.CurlException : Failure when receiving data from the peer
[xUnit.net 00:01:14.5846837]       Stack Trace:
[xUnit.net 00:01:14.5857807]            at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore>d__48.MoveNext()
```

EDIT: Exception was due to not sending the size of the chunk
`await response.WriteAsync($"6\r\ntest {i}\r\n");`

but now on the test/client side, I get all the chunks at once...

Comment: why are you making your code less efficent `await Task.Delay(1 * 1000);`?

Comment: Basicly, don't do this. Just send the data back. [HTTP will chunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) if need's be. All your doing here is slowing your service down not speeding it up.

Comment: it s for testing purpose, i d like to see the answers coming back slowly...

Comment: i have edited the code to use the chunked principles in your link (send the size first, then the text). but on the client side i receive all in one shot.

Comment: Which is what will happen. The transport is chunked. It's sent over HTTP in chunks. The client will wait for all chunks to arrive before preceding. Chunking is used to keep HTTP packets from getting too big, it's not an async communication method. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am expecting to receive them as soon as the server flushes with ```await response.Body.FlushAsync();```. to show that some answers may come much late runtil the server sends the termination chunk

Comment: That's not going to happen. If you want that you need to split the responses up yourself. Async only parks the main thread while it's waiting for an external resource and chunking is a communication protocol implementation. Neither of these things will do what you want them to do. Basically your barking up the wrong tree I'm afraid :)

Comment: Thanks @Liam, I think it clarifies! any suggestion on how to split the responses my self without affecting the client? i don;t think i want to implement pagination, does not really apply.

Comment: Note: I am deploying the app to Google App Engine which does not support websockets...

Comment: To me this sounds like observables would be the way to go. [IObservable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this, I made use of SSE or Server Side Events.
here is the server side in asp.net core:

```
        [HttpGet("testStream")]
        public async Task testStream()
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = 200;
            response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                //the tags are either 'events:' or 'data:' and two \n indicates ends of the msg
                //event: xyz \n\n
                //data: xyz \n\n
                await response.WriteAsync($"data: test {i}\n\n");

                response.Body.Flush();
                await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
            }
            await response.WriteAsync("data:\n\n");
            await response.Body.FlushAsync();
        }
```

and here is the client side:

```
        string page = "http://localhost:8080/api/Stream/testStream";

        //while (!Debugger.IsAttached) Thread.Sleep(500);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (var s = await client.GetStreamAsync(page))
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                string line = null;
                while (null != (line = r.ReadLine()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Usage of ReadAsStringAsync forced wait of all the message in order to proceed.