# Asp.net core endpoint "hangs" when sending response as chunked

Tags: asp.net-core, chunked-encoding

I'm trying to send a response as `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in asp.net core but it fails. Browser hangs (request remains pending) and then says `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`. `curl` says that connection was closed. How to send body chunked correctly ?

This is my endpoint:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/GetMessage", async context =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                // send the first part
                await context.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                // delay to simulate 'work'
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                // send the second part
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
```

**EDIT** (my findings):

The reason I need chunked transfer is because I'm using a technique called http streaming. It is leaving response open and sending parts of file as they become available.

What I've learned is that I don't need to set `Transfer-Encoding` header, I don't need to 'flush' and I need to use `Response.Body.WriteAsync` since I need to write bytes because file is audio (not text). The final piece is that I need to give it some audio mime type or browser will wait for the entire body before calling `progress` callback function. There's some under the hood stuff happening that I don't understand but this is good enough for me.

My server test code:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/GetMessage", async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] = "audio/aac";
                    var buf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hellow world !");
                    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                    await Task.Delay(3000);
                    await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                });
```

Html test page:

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>Hello word</h3>
<script>
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onprogress = e => console.log("progress " + e.currentTarget.response)
xhr.onload = e => console.log("load " + e.currentTarget.response)
xhr.open("GET", "/GetMessage");
xhr.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works as expected. Console prints first part right away and the entire body at the end.

Comment: What version of .net core are you using, please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722936/asp-net-core-1-1-chunked-responses

Comment: It's .net 5.0. I don't know what version of asp.net core this is.