# How Angular handle chunked HTTP response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, http

My ASP.NET API (.NET Core 3.1) application generates an excel file, saves it in local dir, reads like a fileStream and sends it to the client application (Angular 11.2.9). Everythings work fine in the local machine, but these two applications are running in OpenShift. My environment has response size limits and then the excel file is larger than 10 MB Angular starts crashing because it can't read the blob response correctly. To fix this I implemented Chunks in HTTP response. But I don't know how to handle these responses in Angular and I can't find any example of how to do that. Maybe someone can help this out?

My controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateReport([FromBody] ReportDataFilteredModel data)
    {
        if (data.Report == null)
            throw new ApiException("Report was not selected!");

        var filePath = await _reportService.GenerateReport(data);

        var response = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();

        response.DisableBuffering();
        await response.StartAsync();

        int i = 0;

        var chunks = _fileService.ReadChunks(filePath, 1048576).ToList();

        foreach (var block in chunks)
        {
            i++;
            await response.Writer.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(block));
            await response.Writer.FlushAsync();
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Log.Information($"{i} chunk was send. Left {chunks.Count - i} more");
        }

        await response.CompleteAsync();

        Log.Information("Excel was send succesfuly.");
        return Ok();
    }
```

My service.ts:

```
    this.fileService.generateReport(this.reportDataFilteredModel).subscribe(
    (response: Blob) => {
      console.log(response);
      const blob: any = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      fileSaver.saveAs(blob, excelFileName);
      this.notifier.showSuccessNotification();
    },
    (_error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.isExportingData = false;
      this.notifier.showCustomNotification('error', _error.error);
      console.log(_error);
    },
    () => {
      this.isExportingData = false;
    });
```

My API call method:

```
  generateReport(appliedReportFilters: ReportDataFilteredModel): any{
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    Connection: 'keep-alive'
  }),
  responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'arraybuffer',
  reportProgress: true
};

return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/reports`, appliedReportFilters, options)
.pipe(
  catchError(err => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse || err.error instanceof ArrayBuffer || err.error.type === 'application/json') {
          return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (e: Event) => {
                  try {
                      const errmsg = JSON.parse((e.target as any).result);
                      reject(new HttpErrorResponse({
                          error: errmsg.Message,
                          headers: err.headers,
                          status: err.status,
                          statusText: err.statusText,
                          url: err.url ?? ''
                      }));
                  } catch (e) {
                      reject(err);
                  }
              };
              reader.onerror = (e) => {
                  reject(err);
              };
              reader.readAsText(err.error);
          });
      }
      return throwError(err);
  }));}
```

I tried without pipe and how I understand it doesn't have any difference.
I take examples of Chunks from there: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722936/asp-net-core-1-1-chunked-responses)

Comment: Your method of "chunking" shouldn't make any difference when it comes to response size limiting since you are still writing to the same response, just slower. Have you checked that this really gets around that limitation?

Comment: It just works the same as before "chunking". In local, it seems working and sends responses by chunks, but in OpenShift I got the same error.

Comment: Yeah as I suspected then. To really chunk the download of the file you would need to make several requests (and by that getting several smaller responses), using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests. Then you could stitch those responses together in your angular application. But that would most likely also require you to store the generated report to make several requests for the same file which introduces a lot of complexity. It might just be better to see if you can have your response limit increased.